# pointer in c to structure variable

Tags: c, pointers

Hi I have following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
typedef struct test
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c[10];
}tester;

typedef struct done
{
    tester* t;
    int nn;
}doner;

void main()
{
    doner d;
    d.t = (tester*)malloc(sizeof(d.t));
    d.t->a = 10;
    d.t->c[0] = 10;
    printf("%d\n", d.t->a);
    getch();
    return;
}
```

I think the statement:

```
d.t = (tester*)malloc(sizeof(d.t));
```

is incorrect it should be:

```
d.t = (tester*)malloc(sizeof(tester));
```

but when I run this code it is not crashing please let me the why is this.

Comment: what's the problem, every bug is not guaranteed to crash

Comment: 1) conio.h is a non-standard header file. 2) main() shall return int. 3) don't cast malloc()s return value. 4) #include <stdlib.h> 5)  `d.t = malloc(sizeof *d.t);`

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it is not crashing is because it has undefined behavior. The correct code is the second one, but no need for casting.

```
d.t = malloc(sizeof(tester));
```

Also, You need to free the malloc'ed pointer.

On many system, the heap is not checked when writing to the malloc'ed buffer, but only when freeing the allocated memory. In such case, you will probably get some kind of crash when you free the memory.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it's not crashing is a big reason why these sort of memory allocation bugs are so insidious and hard to detect.  Your program only allocates the one structure, and doesn't fill it up, so the fact that it runs past the amount of memory allocated to it doesn't affect anything else.

If your program made more use of dynamically-allocated memory, then either the calls to `malloc`/`free` would trigger a crash because your structure overwrote the heap's linking metadata, or other parts of the program writing to their own malloc'ed data would overwrite your structure.  Either way, not pretty.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right. It should be `sizeof(tester)`, because `d.t` is just a pointer.

Now if you write `sizeof(d.t)` you invoke [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which is not a guarantee of crash. The program may run correctly, run incorrectly, crash, or order a pizza. There is no guarantee of what will happen with a program that has undefined behavior, even prior to the construct that leads to it.

As `free`ing the `malloc`ed memory - in this small sample program you don't need to worry about it, because the system will free the memory after your program exits, but in general you should try to free whatever you've allocated so as to avoid memory leaks in larger programs.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the linker asks the OS to allocate 1MiB of (stack) memory for the program at the start-up. Your program doesn't crash because all of the references are still in the same memory (same address space) which was reserved by the OS for your program. Technically you haven't allocated that memory, but as the pointers are still in the valid memory range so your program can access it. 
This is just like, in most cases, you can write to d.t->c[10] (although valid indexes are 0-9)
Crashes occur when pointers are used which correspond to memory locations outside the allocated memory. Google *Page Fault* for detailed understanding, if you are interested.